# what size of database operation needs batch mode

Tags: java, jdbc

Just curious - what number of inserts / updates / deletes would warrant the usage of jdbc batch

If I have only about 100 odd records to insert / update - should I be using batch ?

This is w.r.t. Oracle database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example: yes, it will be better to use batch mode to insert/update 100 rows.

I would recommend measuring the results of your insert/update/delete operations using both cases: plain statement execution and batch execution and measure the times it takes for both to determine the specific size to use (or don't) the batch operations.

Note that there are other connection related issues that can delay the database operations like opening a connection on every operation or using a single connection for all your database operations. Also, another problem may be creating a new `Connection` manually (`Class.forName(...)` syntax) or retrieving it from a database connection pool.

Comment: Thanks Luiggi - but I actually said 100 not 1000 - I ama ssuming for such a small number batch may not be needed ?

Comment: @akila answer updated. It is basically the same reasoning. There are some frameworks that even tells you to do this from 50 records. As said in my answer, it will be better to measure the results because this is very platform specific to know when and when not. AFAIK 100 is a good number to use batch mode.